# regexp in javascript console.logging out characters instead of the entire pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to use regexp in javascript to match a group of patterns but for some reason when I'm trying to console.log the group, it's just logging out characters instead of the entire pattern. What I am doing wrong? Also, the g flag is required for this pattern.

```
var string = "group1group2group3 group4group4group4 group1group2group3";
var matches = string.match(new RegExp("(group1)(group2)(group3)", "g"));

console.log(matches[0][0]+matches[0][1]+matches[0][2]);
```

**Result:**

gro

**Expected Result:**

group1group2group3

Comment: You're currently only getting the full match in `matches[0]`. To extract the capture groups, use `matchAll` instead, or iterate manually via `.exec` in a loop

Comment: `String#match` with a regex  with a global modifier loses all captures.